# Calculated column not working in SharePoint 2007 list

Tags: 2007, calculated-column-formula

In a nutshell, I have two columns; the standard `[Modified]` and `[ACTION_DATE]`.

I'm using this formula `=IF([Status]="New","","[Modified]")` in the **ACTION_DATE** column to populate it with the last modified date if the status of the ticket is not equal to New.

**The problem:** I have is the formula half works - It will read the status, but the valve it returns in the list is `[Modified]`

[image]

Any assistance offered would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "" before and after [modified] so you get

```
=IF([Status]="New","",[Modified])
```